# Django. Several images for product

Tags: python, django

I want to add several images for my product and already have

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    product_information = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                        args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])

class Images (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

but I can't upload image via admin page. 
admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'category', 'price', 'stock', 'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated', 'category']
    list_editable = ['price', 'stock', 'available']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

How should i change my code to be able add several images for my product using admin page?
And how should I than call images in page code?

Right now i call image using {{ product.image}}

I spent already a lot of time to find answer. Please help. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can use here is Admin inlines that helps you easily edit/updated related items.

```
class ProductImagesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Images

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'category', 'price', 'stock', 'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated', 'category']
    list_editable = ['price', 'stock', 'available']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
    inlines = [ProductImagesInline]
```

Once images you can access them like `product.images.all()`

Comment: django returns NameError: name 'Images' is not defined

Comment: You need to import it from your models at the top

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the [Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline) Admins for the `Image` (yes, you should give it a singular name!) model:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]
```

For properly displaying images in templates, you should consider a thumbnail library like [sorl](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail) or [easy-thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails):

```
# sorl example
{% for image in product.images.all %}
    {% thumbnail image.image "500x500" format="PNG" upscale=False as thumb %}
    #                  ^^^^^ you need the image field here
    <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endfor %}
```

Beyond that, you can access an `Image`'s url via [`image.image.url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url). This is where your original image file will be served. This requires you to have `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` properly configured.

Comment: django returns NameError: name 'Image' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, I took the liberty to change your model name from `'Images'` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    ''''fields''''

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, related_name='images',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

admin.py

from yourapp.models import Product, Images

class InlineImage(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Images

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineImage]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```